# Is a typedef shorthand header file bad practice?

Tags: c++, typedef

Earlier, a friend of mine sent me a block of code over instant message. It took some working to hammer into place, because they had a series of custom types defined in a header they use in all their projects, just for shorthand - byte, ushort, uint, ulong, and so on.

I was about to chastise them for embedding such custom shorthand into their code, but... is it *actually* bad practice? Instant messaging is *not* the normal method for code sharing, and if I'd had the entire functioning project the header with the definitions would have come with it. The shorthand types are all intuitive, and often save typing, but on the other hand that might just lead to laziness.

Is there any kind of official verdict on this?

Comment: "...that might just lead to laziness" Nice one.

Comment: Is compiled language bad practice? The first generation programmer do punchcard and wiring by hand and they are way smarter. Compiled language are easier to learn, and often save time, but on the other hand that might just lead to stupidness. Is there any kind of official verdict on this?

Comment: What about `<cstdint>` ?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion and situation. Never say never, never say always.

Answer (score 1):

If the environment doesn't define the types you want to use, then why not define them yourself? Keeping all such definitions in a single header file helps to prevent inconsistencies. It also means you can base your definitions on the most appropriate types that do already exist, and easily update them if you port to a different platform or compiler.

I cannot see why anyone should consider this bad practice.